# How can I install elementary OS alongside windows 10 without a USB or DVD

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, sd-card, elementaryos

Only way of transferring data to and from my laptop is the SD card port, its the only thing that works, none of my usb ports are working and my dvd drive is dead as well. Also i want it alongside Windows 10 as dual boot not on a virtual machine. Please help!

Comment: If you are familiar with how to make a bootable usb substitute the usb for sd card in the logic and then just use the sd card

Answer (score 0):

You can write the iso to the SD card, then boot from it. Try using a tool such as [Etcher](http://www.etcher.io) or Win32DiskImager.

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool called [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/), which made for problemes like these!